# How to pass Strings through Booleans? yes for true, no for false?

Tags: java, if-statement, boolean

I'm trying to write my first program that uses booleans and if/else statements. It takes the user through various questions and ultimately tells them whether they should eat at home or at a restaurant. This is done through a Scanner object where the user enters "true" or "false". It seems to work well but my question is, how do I allow the user to enter "yes" for "true" and "no" for "false", instead of having them type those words? My assignment specifies they should use yes/no.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HomeOrRestaurant {  
    
    public static void main(String args[]){     
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.println("yes/no");
        
        System.out.println("Did you get paid this week?");
            boolean paid = scan.nextBoolean();          
            if (!paid == true){
            System.out.println("Eat at home.");
            return;
        
        }
        
        else 
        System.out.println("Did you buy groceries this week?");
            boolean boughtGroceries = scan.nextBoolean(); 
            if (boughtGroceries == true){
            System.out.println("Eat at home.");
            return;
        }
            
        else
        System.out.println("Do you have leftovers at home?");
            boolean leftovers = scan.nextBoolean(); 
            if (!leftovers == true){
            System.out.println("Eat at home.");
            return;
        }
            
        else
        System.out.println("Are there enough leftovers for a meal?");
            boolean enoughLeftovers = scan.nextBoolean(); 
            if (!enoughLeftovers == true){
            System.out.println("Eat at a restaurant.");
        }

        else
        System.out.println("Eat at home.");
    }  
}
```

Upon trying to set one of these to "yes" or "no"...

```
        System.out.println("Did you get paid this week?");
            boolean paid = scan.nextBoolean();          
            if (!paid == yes){
            System.out.println("Eat at home.");
            return;
        
        }
```

I get an error telling me that the symbol variable "yes" could not be found. In response I tried to create a local variable "yes" but this did not work. How do I tell my program that "yes" means "true"? Thanks!

Comment: By the way, don't compare booleans; they're already boolean. Just say `if (!paid)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to enter a String, then do not use `nextBoolean`, maybe use `nextLine` or `next`

When you have your String you can test if it is equal to `yes`

```
if (paid.equalsIgnoreCase ("YES"))
```

**edit**

As you are using this pattern a lot, I suggest that you wrap this code up into its own method

Comment: Or, `String input = scan.nextLine();` and then `boolean paid = input.equalsIgnoreCase("yes");` and then `if (paid)` or `if (!paid)`.

Comment: No problem. I also felt the `if (!leftovers == true)` antipattern deserved some attention.

Comment: Thanks a ton! This is exactly what I needed.

Comment: @Squatchy97 Note that in real application code, you can use something like [`BooleanUtils` from Apache commons-lang3](https://github.com/apache/commons-lang/blob/b2e7374bfb91b54d49dfb4d327de639ff1f4b127/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/lang3/BooleanUtils.java#L650), though in this assignment you probably need to work through providing your own implementation.